# How do I troubleshoot status code 500 error for admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-500

I'm getting a status code 500 error when submitting a form on my WordPress website and I was wondering where I can even begin to look into what is causing the error?

Comment: webserver error.log, turn on error reporting, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can on the debug mode with WP_DEBUG_LOG true. After your ajax request your error will be dumped on debug file inside uploads folder.
 Here is the sample on wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

To know more on this please visit [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Note: Please be sure you are adding `wp_die()` after the complete ajax statement.

Thanks